# What is this piece?

Tags: doors, closet

I am repairing some closet doors and found an odd setup in one of the rooms with wheel assemblies that slide into a bracket type deal that slides into the frame.

I've already found replacement wheels (here Prime-Line N 6599 Mirror Door Roller Assembly, 1-1/2 In., Plastic Roller, Ball Bearings, Concave (Single Pack) https://a.co/d/4SL3Tme) but I can't find the bracket anywhere.

Anyone know what it's called? [image]
[image]

Comment: Google Lens pulls the first image right up: https://www.walmart.com/ip/CRL-N6872-Wardrobe-Door-Roller-Mounting-Bracket/957398053. Nothing in stock, though.

Comment: https://www.dkhardware.com/wardrobe-door-roller-mounting-bracket-n6872-product-37382.html